# Recover unreadable directory on ext4 partition

Tags: 14.04, filesystem, data-recovery, ext4

One of my directories in a ext4 filesystem on my SSD became unredable and I need to recover the files.

Here is what I did to crash the filesystem:

I accidentally created 1.5 million small files in the directory and then deleted them with a `find . -name "xyz*" -delete`.

When I noticed the the directory file remaind huge, I booted into a live system (Ubuntu 14.04) and did an `fsck -D /dev/sdb1` to shrink the directory. No errors.

After booting my real system again, the partition was only mounted read-only and every subsequent run of `fsck -f -y /dev/sdb1` complains about the same errors that a directory block contains unallocated blocks and claims to fix it.

Unfortunately the next run of fsck shows the exact same errors as if the changes weren't written to disk at all. When I try to cd into the directory I get an error that it is unreadable.

I'm now in the process to cread a copy of the partition.

What are my options to fix the directory? Is single file recovery with `foremost` or `magicrescue` my only option ? Or is there a tool that could try to recover the whole directory (besides `fsck`) ?

Answer (score 0):

The `fsck.ext4` shipped with Ubuntu 15.10 is much better than the version shipped with 14.04 and was able to recover the file system.

Many files are now in lost+found, but at least nothing seems to be completely lost.